# Jenkins + Gradle + Artifactory plugin (Successful build & deployment - failed end result)

Tags: jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration, artifactory

We have recently set up a Jenkins job which publishing the resulting file to Artifactory.

For some reason, the plugin seems to be causing that job to fail. The deployment is correct and the build finishes successfully. However, the end result is failure.

We are using Gradle 2.8

The Jenkins log is below:

```
Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version: 2.4.7
[Warning] No Gradle build configured
+ export GRADLE_HOME=/root/gradle/gradle-2.8
+ export NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
+ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
+ export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/gradle/gradle-2.8/bin:/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
+ gradle clean fC fM test jar artifactoryPublish
[build_86dm4wztwe32gv2is1jb93c3t$_run_closure3$_closure12$_closure13@1ef31f71][0][buildinfo] Properties file found at '/tmp/buildInfo766351637837418080.properties'
:cleanQuerydslSourcesDir
:clean
:initQuerydslSourcesDir
:compileQuerydslwarning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7

//BLABLABLABLABLA

:compileJavawarning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:processResources
:classes
:compileTestJavawarning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7

:processTestResources
:testClasses
:flywayClean
:flywayMigrate
:test
2016-04-05 09:53:53.338  INFO 10455 --- [       Thread-5] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@368edf2b: startup date [Tue Apr 05 09:52:46 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-04-05 09:53:53.351  INFO 10455 --- [       Thread-5] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
:jar
:generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication
:artifactoryPublish
Deploying artifact: http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/artifactory/libs-release-local/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jar
Deploying artifact: http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/artifactory/libs-release-local/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pom
Deploying build descriptor to: http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/artifactory/api/build
Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/artifactory/webapp/builds/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/127

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 37.345 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.8/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Finished: FAILURE
```

The problem seems to be enabling the Artifactory Plugin. If we don't run `artifactoryPublish` the end result will still fail. However, if we disable the Artifactory plugin and only build the project everything works like a charm.

Summary:

- Plugin + Build + Publish = Successful Build + Successful Publish + Failed Result
- Plugin + Build = Successful Build + Failed Result
- Build = Successful Build + Successful Result

Any ideas to help me fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is an unresolved issue with Jenkins Gradle plugin 1.24: [JENKINS-27632](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27632)

Current workaround is to revert to v1.23

Comment: Thanks  RaGe. I've tried downgrading to v1.23 and still got the same error. Also, the other builds that don't involve the Artifactory plugin work like a charm. This makes me think that the plugin can be causing the issue, but I haven't found any information about it.